# Image not showing up in img tag

Tags: html, image, tags, src

I am working on using the [OMDB API](http://www.omdbapi.com) and I get the url of the poster of a movie.

For example: https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg

When you view that image in the browser by clicking on the link, it is perfectly visible. But when I use it in an `img` tag, it does not find the image:

`<img src="https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg">`

Here the above code implemented:
[image]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: When I clicked that link it says: Referral Denied

Comment: That image is blocked if the client is not logged onto the system. I suggest hosting the image somewhere where you can access it without having to be logged in.

Comment: I just visited the link, its working fine, an image is being displayed! **is this issue solved now?**

Comment: The image is not hosted somewhere where you have to be logged in, since I'm not logged in and can view it. @AmitThakur I said it is fine when you visit the link, that is not the issue. When using the link in an `img` tag, that creates a problem

Comment: the image link you mentioned in your post is a public image link,and can be viewed or used anywhere in a web doc, Make sure you have **show image** option enabled in your browser, this is workin foR me in img tag

Comment: @AmitThakur So you are saying you can view the image in my updated OP? That is an img tag with that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMDB blocks direct linking of the images from other sites (as yours). So linking the url you get from the response will lead to the "Referral Denied" message and the image not showing.

However, OMDB seems to have the new Poster API that self-rehosts the images, but a donation is required to use it as evident on the site:

> New Poster API The Poster API is currently in beta being tested by the
>   sites friendly donators.
>
> Donators get your key and start testing!

and

> 1/1/15
>
> - You can now search by type! (movie, series, episode etc.) Dupes
> - have been removed from database.
> - **Poster API images updated.**

Comment: Thank you! Others found the issue but I did not understand their explanation fully. I am using OMDB at the moment, but didn't know the new Poster API was to solve that issue, I'll check it out to donate then!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to display these images you can create a php file that returns the image data and just link to it like so

```
<img src='link/to/php/image.php?i=imdb-image.jpg'/>
```

image.php

```
<?php
    $img = $_REQUEST['i'];
    $image_mime = getimagesize($img)['mime'] ;
    header("Content-type: " .$image_mime);
    echo file_get_contents($img);
?>
```